# Can you access standard Windows strings like 'Cancel'?

Tags: c#, windows, localization, dialog

I am building a Windows dialog box that has the standard 'OK' and 'Cancel' buttons. Given that Windows uses the same button text in its own dialogs is there a way for me to grab the correct strings to use on the buttons?

This way my application will have the correct strings no matter which language is being used, without me needing to localize it for lots of different languages myself. I am using C# but can happily use platform invoke to access an OS method if needed.

NOTE: Yes, I can easily localize the resources but I do not want to find and have to enter the zillion different language strings when it must be present within windows already. Please do not answer by saying localize the app!

Comment: Are you using WinForms, WPF, SilverLight?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Visual Studio: File + Open + File, type c:\windows\system32\user32.dll.  Open the String Table node and double click String Table.  Scroll down to 800.

Microsoft takes a pretty no-nonsense stance against relying on these resource IDs.  Given the number of programmers who've done what you're contemplating, it is however unlikely they can ever change these numbers.  You'll need to P/Invoke LoadLibrary() and LoadString().

However, your ultimate downfall on this plan is Vista/Win7 Ultimate with MUI language packs.  Which allows the user to switch between languages *without* updating the resource strings in the DLLs.  Such an edition will always have English strings.

Comment: I wrote an example of how to load Windows ressources like this, and it seems to work well even in multi language environments: http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/csharp/csharp.html#windows_text_resources

Comment: When MUI language packs are enabled, `LoadString` loads correct localized resources so you should be fine. The only problem is that to find ID's of these resources, you have to browse `C:\Windows\System32\<locale>\user32.dll.mui` files instead (You can rename .mui to .dll and then open them in VS).

Comment: You can also use ResourceHacker to analyze all resources (not only strings) in a DLL or MUI file.

Answer (score 4):

see `MB_GetString` which claims to do exactly this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn910915(v=vs.85).aspx

however, it seems to require runtime linkage:

http://undoc.airesoft.co.uk/user32.dll/MB_GetString.php

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you use the standard [`MessageBox.Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba3x8zfh.aspx) function and pass it approriate parameters it will automatically localize the [yes/no/okay/cancel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messageboxbuttons.aspx) buttons for you.

What is more interesting is how you localize the message text.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no standard, supported way to do this. Yes, Windows does store these strings and it's (with some effort) possible to obtain them, but there is no guarantee that they'll remain in the same location and under the same identifier from version to version.

While you might not *want* this to be the answer, the answer is, indeed, to localize your application. If you're localizing everything else (as you'd have to, unless you *just* wanted `OK` and `Cancel` to be localized), I'm not sure why it would be any great effort to include localized values for `OK` and `Cancel` as well.

Comment: The question clearly says: "Please do not answer by saying localize the app!"

Comment: @Eduardo: It's the only valid answer. I didn't answer just by saying "localize the app"; I answered by saying "No, it isn't possible to do what you're after. The only way to obtain a localized string is to localize the app yourself." It's a perfectly valid--and correct--answer.

Comment: Do not agree, sorry. There other two answers are correct and address the question. Ahh, and I was not the downvoter.

Comment: But if you are localizing your app and you want to be able to refer to the buttons by name, it would sure be nice to have a straightforward way of programmatically asking Windows to tell you what the current button text is. Unfortunately, there's no strict guarantee that the UI locale being displayed in your app will be that of the current locale being used for the system.

Comment: Always dangerous to say there is no supported way, for an API as large as Windows's... now Mordachai has posted a link to the proper (standard, supported) API function and you get downvoted.