# sendkeys to open dialog that open from button click in a webbrowser

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, sendkeys

I use webcontrol to open a webpage, after page is loaded in the webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted method I use the following code to click a button that opens an Open dialog.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CsvFile").InvokeMember("click");
```

How can I control (sendkeys, click the Open button etc.) the dialog from code ??

Comment: Is the dialog a window.alert or something else?

Comment: It is an OpenFile dialog.

Comment: Check the solution in the following question.  You should be able to use the same technique. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31066190/c-sharp-webbrowser-programmatically-close-js-confirm-box